# Relayout of children of LinearLayout stops working when setting new LayoutParams from code

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a HorizontalScrollView in Android that looks like the following in the xml.

```
<com.se.myapp.MyScroller
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:scrollbars="none">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/scroller_layout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <include layout="@layout/item_1" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <include layout="@layout/item_2" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <include layout="@layout/item_3" />
        </LinearLayout>                        
    </LinearLayout>
</com.se.myapp.MyScroller>
```

This is how an item looks in xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">       
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" "/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I then implement it like below in the code. I override the onLayout to change the width of the layouts that the items reside in to reflect the size of the screen of the phone.

```
public class MyScroller extends HorizontalScrollView 
{
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) 
    {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.scroller_layout);
        mNoOfItems = layout.getChildCount();

        int itemLayoutWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
        for(int i = 0; i < mNoOfItems; i++)
        {
            View child = (View)layout.getChildAt(i);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams newLayout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(itemLayoutWidth , LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
            child.setLayoutParams(newLayout);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

The items that are included in the xml are just LinearLayouts with a textview in it (they will be more complex later). The problem I face is that if I change the layout of the LinearLayouts in onLayout all of the sudden the items will not relayout when the text in the textviews changes. So if I have a text like "test" in item 1 for example, and change that text to "test123" dynamically when the app runs, the "123" will not be shown because the layout of the textview is not updated. The weird thing is that if I don't change the layout of the LinearLayout in onLayout but put it hardcoded to 540px in the xml for example, the textview will update its layout when the text changes. I even noticed that if I hardcode it to 540px in the xml, and then just get the layoutParams in the code and set it immediately again without changing anything like below, it will also stop working.

```
child.setLayoutParams(child.getLayoutParams());
```

Is there any difference with setting the layout of a LinearLayout from xml than from code? Or how can this behavior happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, I had to call super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom); after I called child.setLayoutParams(newLayout);, however I rewrote it so that I change the layoutparams from onSizeChanged instead, which worked good.